# Script to record all touch events on an android device

Tags: android, adb

I have an android device with developer mode enabled.

I would like to write a script which I can push using adb which will have the android record all touch events, even while disconnected from my computer.

Is this possible and how would I accomplish it?

Comment: Unless you're rooted, you can't.  There is no way for any app except the foreground app to get touch events.  You'd have to get them directly from the linux dev files as root.